# Does CSS have a selector for selecting when in more than one class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following:

```
<a class="nav disabled">Test</a>
```

Is there some way I can specify the background-color if the address has BOTH the "nav" and "disabled" class markers? In other words a selector that will select only the last of the three below:

```
<a class="nav">Test1</a>
<a class="disabled">Test2</a>
<a class="nav disabled">Test3</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
.nav.disabled { .... }
```

this has [side effects in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html), but is otherwise supported by every browser.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the class selectors:

```
a.nav.disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS rule for

```
<a class="nav disabled">Test3</a>
```

is

```
a.nav.disabled {}
```

or

```
.nav.disabled {}
```